# Referring to a variable in a variable

Tags: vb.net, variables

This is probably quite simple to do but I am very new to visual basic so please bear with me.
I know similar questions have been asked, but none of them seem to answer my question. I have an array created earlier, and want to randomly choose one value and change it. 
I have two random number generators ('GeneratorP1' and 'GeneratorP2'), which are added to some text a create a variable name which is stored in Loc1:

```
Dim Loc1 As String
        Loc1 = "th" & GenerateP1() & "(" & GenerateP2() & ")"
```

eg: th5(4) is stored in Loc1

How would I go about changing the value of th5(4)?

EDIT: I have 5 arrays (th1, th2, th3, th4, th5), with indexes up to 4

Comment: How is it no-one created the adamantium user name until 8 days before this question was asked?

Comment: @noonand I've had it for over a year on other stack exchange sites.

Comment: @noonand [usernames aren't unique](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=adamantium).

Comment: @JamesThorpe I did not know that, consider me schooled for today!

Comment: Do have one array or five arrays or you have an array of index 5?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - How does a non unique user name work?  How does stackexchange know which user is trying to log in?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Because they're display names and not true usernames?  I log in using my google account, or facebook - I don't think I have a true "username" on stack exchange.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - good point.  I think I use Google as well, I had forgotten that since i am pretty much always logged on!

Comment: if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (which I'm not sure I am), you're wanting to use the string stored in variable Loc1 as a variable name?

You said you created an array earlier, so why do you need to randomly generate the variable (GenerateP1) and the index (GenerateP2)? If you have a single array, can't you use randomly pickthe index, then assign whatever value you want to it?

```
th5(GenerateP2()) = "my value"
```

If you had multiple arrays (th1, th2, th3, etc.) I would suggest using a Dictionary to randomly pick which array to use. Alternatively you could use a multidimensional array and generate both indexes

```
th(GenerateP1(), GenerateP2()) = "my value"
```

If possible, you should consider using a List instead of an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having multiple arrays, use a 2-dimensional array

```
Dim th(5,4)
```

So instead of trying to reference th1(3), you could use th(1,3) or th5(2) would be th(5,2)